# Get variables don't get send over to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am struggling to get something to work for the last 2 days and I am out of ideas.

Basicly I have an image overview with a bunch of thumbnails and if I'd press a button every thumb gets a checkbox (this works with an hidden element) and a div appears with a button that will trigger an AJAX (get also tried post) to a PHP script.

This is the HTML roughly:

```
$output .= '<div id="edit-menu" style="display:none; position:fixed; top:150px; right:0px;" class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading">Bewerk geselecteerde items</div>
</div>';
foreach($results as $file){
    if($config->ajax){
        $image = $file->image;
    }else{
        $image = $file->image;
    }
    if($image){
        $output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
        <div class="edit-wrapper" style="display:none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="' . $file->id . '"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><div class="caption">
        <h4>' . $file->title . '</h4><p><a href="' . $config->urls->root .  'view-image/' . $file->id . '" class="label label-danger fancybox fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" rel="tooltip" title="Bekijk">Bekijk</a>
        <a href="' . $pages->get('/register-use/')->url ."?picture_id=" .  $file->id . '" id="' . $file->id  . '" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p></div>';
        $img = $image->size(150,150);
        $output .= '<img src="' . $img->url . '" alt="...">';
        $output .= '</div></div>';
    }

}
$output .= '<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-selected-items" value="Verwijder"/>';
$output .= "</div>";
```

This works and yes I know it's ugly but that is because I changed it a lot over time.
And this is my JQuery AJAX request with a bunch of other stuff to collect the data from the checkboxes:

```
$("#delete-selected-items").on("click", function(){
    if(confirm("Weet je zeker dat je de geselecteerde items wilt verwijderen?")) {
    var checked = []
    $("input[name='del[]']:checked").each(function ()
    {
        checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
    console.log(checked);
    $.get('ajax-requests/delete-images', {'del[]':checked} , function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
return false;

});
```

And in my PHP script I have the following:

```
 <?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print_r($_GET);

?>
```

This echoes `GET Array()` and thats it... There's no GET variables

It's also worth mentioning there's another form ont he same page just above the provided html.

Who can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing {'del[]':checked}   to   {'del': checked}  and accessing at PHP as $_GET['del'] ?

Comment: What does console.log(checked); give you?

Comment: its seems that if `checked` is empty , it does not send the request with `del` parameter. but if there is a value in it, it sends the request with the `del`. i just tested your code and this is what i found out. its possible that `$("input[name='del[]']:checked")` is not returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$.get('ajax-requests/delete-images', {del: checked} , function(data){
```

to

```
$.get('ajax-requests/delete-images/', {del: checked} , function(data){
```

I'm going to jump of a bridge

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name='del[]']:checked").each(function (index, obj)
{
    checked.push(parseInt($(obj).val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know, but these are some things I would try:

- You really need a tool that will tell you the data you are sending to the server, like Firebug.  Click the Net tab and you can see exactly what you are sending to the server, and receiving.  This will tell you if your problem is on the client or server.
- It would be really handy to know the output of "console.log(checked);".  That would tell us if anything is going to be sent to the server.
- You need to verify the number of elements that are being matched by your jquery select string. Try this: console.log($("input[name='del[]']:checked").length)  This will tell you if any elements are actually being matched.  I suspect the square brackets in the name of the element is confusing the jquery selecter, so nothing is actually getting matched.  Try just naming them "del" with no brackets and see if that works.
- And finally, you need a console.log statement inside your "each" function loop that outputs the value of .value(), so you know that the correct values are being pushed onto the array

Comment: The console.log(checked)  gives me [1078] where 1078 is the ID in the checkbox.
Also, I've checked the NET tab and I cannot see any get variables being send over.

Comment: Since you're passing by GET, the variables would show up in the URL itself, like this: ajax-requests/delete-images?del[]=1078  or maybe this: ajax-requests/delete-images?del=1078

Comment: Since this action is doing something destructive (deleting stuff), it is highly recommended to use POST instead of GET, so you might want to change that anyway.

Comment: I changed it to GET after I initiually used POST when I saw that $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] echoed GET/

Answer (score 0):

So, few things you may want to change.

Change the input name from xx[] to xx
And then use the below and see how you go. Ask if you need help.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/sxJ65/3/)

HTML (sample only)

```
<div id="edit-menu" class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">Bewerk geselecteerde items</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="edit-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="one">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="two">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="three">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="four">
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="five">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-selected-items" value="Verwijder"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var checked = [];
    $('#delete-selected-items').click(function(){
        $("input[name='del']:checked").each(function () {
            checked.push( $(this).val() );
            //use the below ONLY if your values are numbers;
            //checked.push( +($(this).val()) );
        });
        alert(checked);
        $.get('ajax-requests/delete-images', {del: checked} , function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing it here but does the url in your ajax get need to have the .php extension?  Otherwise, you can change the PHP to just have `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see any parameters that are being sent to the page, GET or POST.